# "Tous" or "touts"

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

I was recently working with an anglophone whose second language is French on a project, and they were dead certain that rather than using the form "tous" in :

> Tous les hommes

it should rather be

> Touts les hommes.

A quick check in a grammar revealed that I was correct that the m.p. form of tout is "tous." However, a Google ngram of "touts" reveals that it is used, though far less than tous.

[image: Ngram of touts]

Also, [wictionary quotes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/touts) Georges-Louis Leclerc de Buffon in Histoire des animaux, II *(emphasis added)*:

> En considérant sous ce point de vue les êtres organisés et leur reproduction, un individu n’est qu’un tout uniformément organisé dans toutes ses parties intérieures, un composé d’une infinité de figures semblables et de parties similaires, un assemblage de germes ou de petits individus semblables, lesquels peuvent tous se développer de la même façon, suivant les circonstances, **et former de nouveaux touts composés comme le premier.**

Is there a situation where "touts" is correct?

Comment: un tout is a complete whole or whole. tous is the masculine plural form of the adjective: tout, tous, toute, toutes,

Comment: `touts les hommes` is clearly incorrect

Comment: @Kii Yeah that's what I said...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Touts*** is correct when the rare plural of the substantive ***tout*** : *un **tout**, des **touts***. Buffon's quote *de nouveaux **touts** composés comme le premier* is then correct.

The plural of ***tout*** when an adjective or a pronoun is ***tous*** and the plural of ***toute*** (feminine) is ***toutes***.

The adverb ***tout*** is invariable e͟x͟c͟e͟p͟t when used before a feminine word starting with a consonant:

> *Ils sont **tout** rouges.*

> *Elles sont **toutes** rouges et **tout** énervées.* (?!)

---

***Touts*** est correct quand c'est le pluriel (rare) du substantif ***tout*** : *un **tout**, des **touts***. La citation de Buffon *de nouveaux **touts** composés comme le premier* est donc correcte.

Le pluriel de ***tout*** adjectif ou pronom est ***tous*** et au féminin, le pluriel de ***toute*** est ***toutes***.

L'adverbe ***tout*** est invariable s͟a͟u͟f devant un mot adjectif féminin qui commence par une consonne ou un *H* aspiré :

> *Ils sont **tout** rouges.*

> *Elles sont **toutes** rouges et **tout** énervées.* (?!)